# Join two tables with hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am looking to create a DAO which represents a join of two tables with Java Hibernate. Here is the SQL I'd like to represent (Postgres 9.6 incase that matters):

```sql
SELECT tableOneValue, tableTwoValue
FROM table_one, table_two
WHERE table_one_filter = 2 AND table_one_id = table_two_id;
```

These tables have a OneToOne relationship.

Table1.java

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="table_one")
public class TableOneDao implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "table_one_id")
    private int tableOneId;

    @Column(name = "table_one_value")
    private String tableOneValue;


    @Column(name = "table_one_filter")
    private int tableOneFilter;
}
```

Table2.java

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="table_two")
public class TableTwoDao implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "table_twp_id")
    private int tableTwpId;

    @Column(name = "table_two_value")
    private String tableTwoValue;
}
```

I'm very new to hibernate so maybe this isn't the right way to think with it. What I would love to do is define a SomeDao class where I can do: `daoManager.findAll(SomeDao.class, Pair.of("tableOneFilter", 2));`

This would return a `List<SomeDao>` where we get all the rows that satisfy tableOneFilter == 2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `@OneToOne` and `@JoinColumn` annotation.

Pay special attention to the `userDetail` attribute mapping.

For example, the user class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "USR_ID")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String username;

   @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
   private String password;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="USR_DET_ID")
   private UserDetail userDetail;

   // Add Constructor, Setter and Getter methods
}
```

And this user details class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetail {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "USR_DET_ID")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name = "EMAIL")
   private String email;

   @Column(name = "DBO")
   private LocalDate dob;

   // Add Constructor, Setter and Getter methods
}
```

Check the full code [here](https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-one-to-one-association-example).

Comment: This looks like it would link the USR_DET_ID to the USR_ID because it would default to the ID, but what if you want to join on NOT the id? So let's say User had another long field called "thing", how would you tell the @JoinColumn to match that ID instead?

Comment: @Cotlin, You could do that, but you would need to use OneToMany instead of OneToOne and then on the class that you have your "thing" you need to use ManyToOne. Check this out: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JPA query which will work with your existing entity structure with the latest version of hibernate.

SELECT t1.tableOneValue, t2.tableTwoValue
FROM TableOneDao AS t1 JOIN TableTwoDao AS t2 ON t1.table_one_id = t2.table_two_id 
WHERE t1.table_one_filter = ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a JPQL statement which is much better. Here is the sample solution:

```
SELECT NEW com.test.package.dao(t1.valueOne, t2.valueTwo)
FROM table_one t1 JOIN table_two t2
WHERE t1.filter = 2 AND t1.id = t2.id;
```

Please refer to [this link](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select) and jump to the section where it mentions **Result Classes (Constructor Expressions)**. Hope it helps. Thanks.